# Calling a previously defined function in another (PHP)

Tags: php, function, user-defined-functions, nested-function

I've been reading answers on SO questioning the need for nested functions, but I still haven't figured out 1) why my code is erroneous and 2) how I can fix it to make what I wrote work OR change my script so it's more acceptable (to the parser but also to experienced developers). Let me mention that I am new to PHP OOP...

The idea is I want to use a function that I previously defined in a whole lot of other functions, so it'll save me rewriting the code each time.

Here's the faulty code, then, which throws a fatal error "Call to undefined function" pointing to the line in which I call selectMediaIds () within getMedia ()... (FYI I purposefully omitted the variable initialization, constructor, getters, setters, etc. to make my post more compact.)

```
<?php

class MediaManager {

private function selectMediaIds (MObject $object) {
    $medias = array ();
    $req = $this -> _db -> query ('SELECT media_idMedia FROM mObject_has_media WHERE mObject_idmObject = ' . $object -> id ());
    while ($data = $req -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $medias[] = $data;
    }
    $req -> closeCursor ();
    return $medias;
}

public function getMedia (MObject $object) {
    $medias = array ();
    $mediaIds = selectMediaIds ($object);
    if ($mediaIds[0] != null) {
        foreach ($mediaIds as $id) {
            $req = $this -> _db -> query ('SELECT * FROM media WHERE idMedia = ' . $id);
            $req -> fetch ();
            $medias[] = $req;
            //$medias[] = new Media ($req);
        }
    return $medias;
    }
}}?>
```

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You're calling a __method__ in an __object__, not simply a __function__; so `$mediaIds = $this->selectMediaIds ($object);`

Comment: As a comment on coding style, it is unusual to put spaces around `->` and `()` as you have here; e.g. `$req -> fetch ();` would normally be written `$req->fetch();`

Comment: @MarkBaker: Ah, the ubiquitous $this... I knew it was going to get me one day... :p Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @IMSoP : The spaces before () are actually added automatically by IDEs I use for other languages (namely MonoDevelop in C# or Eclipse, the rare times I've used it...) so I figured I'd do the same when using Notepad++ to code in PHP. The ones before and after -> I simply added to harmonize the whole thing (call me stupid!) I'll just finish this project this way so my code is uniform (and I don't feel like bothering to go through the whole thing again to scrap all the unnecessary spaces) but I'll keep your advice in mind for the next project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing to do with "nested" functions, and calling a function from another to reuse code is indeed the whole point of using functions in the first place.

Your problem is that `selectMediaIds` is not a global function, but a private method of the class `MediaManager` - it is "part of" that class, and can reference the current instance of the class under the magic variable `$this`.

In order to call such a method, you have to call it using the `object->method` notation, so you need to use `$this->selectMediaIds($object)`. That tells PHP that you want to call `selectMediaIds` within that particular object `$this`, which you know is an instance of class `MediaManager`.

This is the same operation as you are using with your DB call when you write `$req->fetch();`

Answer (score 1):

`selectMediaIds` is defined in a scope of class `MediaManager`. That's why it should be accesed as `$this->selectMediaIds()`.

Invoking `selectMediaIds` without defining scope means that the scope is global, in which you definitely has no `selectMediaIds` function defined.